# Filtering out empty values from a dimension

Tags: crossfilter

Here's how my csv data file is formated, some of the values are missing:

```
runtime,genres,production_companies,release_date
105,Action|Comedy|Science Fiction,Columbia Pictures|Happy Madison Productions,7/16/15,1575
105,,Columbia Pictures|Happy Madison Productions,7/16/15,1575
```

This is the code I'm using to group all the unique genres by total runtime:

```
    var genres = data.dimension(function(d) { return d.genres.split("|"); }, true).filter(!"")

    var group = genres.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.runtime});
```

When I console.log the length of genres:

```
console.log(genres.top(Infinity)
```

It excludes empty values from the dimension(i.e. 26960 instead of 26983) but when I console.log the group:

```
console.log(group.all());
```

It includes the empty values as the first object in the array printed out:

```
(21) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
{key: "", value: 1625}
1:
{key: "Action", value: 250216}
2:
{key: "Adventure", value: 156181}
```

I can filter the group for empty keys like so:

```
    console.log(group.all().filter(function(d){return d.key !== ""}));
```

And it returns the correct array but this only works for the console. I'm trying to create a barchart with dc.js and I don't know how to filter the group for keys that aren't empty, without using the filter function on the group which I can't use.

I'm new to javascript and data-visualisation and having a hard time grasping the crossfilter library, so excuse any mistakes I might have made.

---

Here's how I solved it:

```
var group = genres.group().reduce(add_item, remove_item, initialise);

    function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
        return {
            all:function () {
                return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                    //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                    return d.key !== ""; // if integers only
                });
            }
        };
    }

var filtered = remove_empty_bins(group);
```

Found a function to create a fake group by passing the original group into a function then filtering it.